# Maximize sum of $(x_1+\dots+x_k)^2$ on the unit $n$-sphere

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

> Given any positive integer $n$, let $t(n)$ be the smallest real number such that for any real numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$, the following inequality holds $$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x_1+\dots+x_k)^2 \leqslant t(n) \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2.$$ Please give an expression for $t(n)$.

---

**Attempt:**

The problem is equivalent to calculating the maximum of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x_1+\dots+x_k)^2$ on the unit $n$-sphere $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2=1$. Let

$$ A := \begin{pmatrix}
n & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1\\
n-1 & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1\\
n-2 & n-2 & n-2 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x_1+\cdots+x_k)^2=xAx^T$$

where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. According to Lagrange multipliers, we know the problem is equivalent to calculating the maximum eigenvalue of $A$. Then I'm stuck. The book says that the answer is

$$\frac{1}{4\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4n+2}\right)}.$$

It is really amazing. I would appreciate it if someone could please give me some hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that the inverse of $A$ is
$$B_n=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
& -1 & 2 & -1 \\
&&&\ddots\\
&&& -1 & 2 &-1\\
&&&& -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the characteristic polynomial $P_n$ of the tridiagonal matrix $B_n$ satisfies the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant):
$$P_{n}(x)=P_{n-1}(x)(x-2)-P_{n-2}(x)$$
with $P_1(x)=x-1$ and $P_0(x)=1$.

See also the related question [Eigenvalues of tridiagonal symmetric matrix with diagonal entries $2$ and subdiagonal entries $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177957)

Answer (score 5):

We will use the result of [(Fonseca, 2004, On the eigenvalues of some tridiagonal matrices)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/144007447.pdf). For that, let's write the matrix in another way
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x_1+\cdots+x_k)^2=\mathbf{yAy}^T$$
such that
$$\mathbf{y}:=(x_\color{red}{n},x_\color{red}{{n-1}},...,x_\color{red}{1})^T$$
$$\mathbf{A}:=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2\\
1  & 2 & 3 & \cdots & 3\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n
\end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is the one defined in section 1. Then applying the theorem 2.1, the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$ is
$$\begin{align}
\lambda_0&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}  \right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4n+2}  \right)}\\
&=\color{red}{\frac{1}{4\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4n+2}  \right)}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: In case the link is broken, the DOI is https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2005.08.047