# Smallest eigenvalue of a variant of the line graph Laplacian

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I would like to calculate a lower bound on the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix $$M = e_1 e_1^\top + L$$

where $L$ is the Laplacian of the line graph on $T$ vertices:
$$1 -2 -3 -4-\ldots -T $$
and $e_1$ is the unit vector $(1,0,0,\ldots, 0)$.

Equivalently,
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & & & & & \vdots \\
0 & \ldots & \ldots &-1&2& -1 \\
0 & \ldots & \ldots &0 &-1& 1  \end{pmatrix}$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: Well, if its just the Laplacian the min eigenvalue is 0. This is a rank 1-update but most of the literature is about upper-bounding the change in eigenvalue for a rank-1 update

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694859/339790)

Comment: This matrix is actually the matrix of the discretized second derivative operator with [Dirichlet-Neumann boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Dirichlet-Neumann_Case). The link gives an explicit formula for the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the many commentators. An exact solution is given in [this result by da Fonseca](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/144007447.pdf) (eigenvalue, eigenvector) pairs $(\lambda_k, v_k)$ with

$$\lambda_k = 4 \sin^2 \left( \frac{2k+1}{4k+2} \pi \right)$$

and

$$v_k(j) = \sin \left(\frac{2k+1}{2n+1} \cdot j \pi \right).$$

Note that the vector $v_k(j)$ is not normalized but a normalization can be calculated using the [Sum of Cosines of Multiples of an Angle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Cosines_of_Multiples_of_Angle) formula and the identity $1 - \cos(\theta) = 2 \sin^2(\theta/2)$. The normalization of $v_0$ is $\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{2}$.